# Has LargeCoin shipped any hardware yet?

Tags: asic, mining-hardware

[LargeCoin](http://largecoin.com/) announced their ASIC mining technology [back in March 2012](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=67505.0), with an estimated delivery of July 2012.

"ttul" in Bitcointalk, who made the announcement, also said "Expected delivery is July 2012. [If we miss our delivery deadline, then we will return deposits in full.](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=67505.msg797975#msg797975)"

Have they delivered any units? Did anyone order any? Has there been a more recent comment anywhere on when they will deliver?

Answer (score 2):

Some people pre-ordered Largecoin units, but they never took deposits from anyone.